# Problemas con caracteres especiales mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

bien como lo menciono: Tengo una base de datos sencilla con una sola tabla por cuestión de ser un prueba en donde TODO (la base de datos, la tabla, los campos text) está con un cotejamiento "utf8_general_ci" entonces a la hora de leer desde php el campo text que tiene ñññ'´0ó molesta y aparece exactamente ���\'�0�

consulta.php:

```
<?php 

    require("conexion.php");

    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `administrador`";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

     $barrios = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $local = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $barrios['nombre']);

    echo $local;

?>
```

Base de datos en mysql:

[image: Cotejamiento base de datos]

Tabla mysql:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

datos tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Chicos esto es lo de lo más importante en mi proyecto y de verdad no encuentro salida
Si alguien sabe qué debo hacer, se lo agradezco enserio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el **Cotejamiento** de la tabla o las columnas a:

```
utf8_spanish_ci
```

Debes tener muy en cuenta que en `HTML` también debes incluir la siguiente etiqueta.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

En la conexión a la base de datos puedes realizar lo siguiente, para evitar traer errores de caracteres especiales.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php
    $c = @new mysqli('', '', '', '');
    if ($c->connect_error) {
        die('Error de conexión: ' . $c->connect_error);
    }
    if (!$c->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $c->error);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Oye sí
Con añadir la útlima funcion me ha corrido perfecto!!
Lamento si esta es una pregunta duplicada, realmente me metí hasta con xampp configurando el defaultcharset y demás y ya llevaba bastante tiempo viendome sin salida
Muchas gracias a quienes respondieron, son muy amables :)
Suerte !!

Comment: @DianaDiana Suele pasar, puedes buscar preguntas similares antes de crear una pregunta así puedes evitar todo estos malos entendidos, son similares en sí, pero un poco más optimizado a solucionar el problema con 3 ejemplos que va desde la base de datos, a php, y HTML. Saludos :)